# Kendo UI Mobile - Remote views nested in <form runat="server"> issue

Tags: asp.net, html, kendo-ui

Is there a pattern or anything I can do to load remote asp.net views properly? I have my index page that basically looks like this:

Index page works fine using `new kendo.mobile.Application(document.forms[0])`:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div data-role="view" id="indexPageInitialView"> ... </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="indexPageOtherView"> ... </div>
</form>
```

Remote view page issue:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div data-role="view" id="remoteView1"> ... </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="remoteView2"> ... </div>
</form>
```

I know Kendo loads remote views that can be [at most] descendants within the body tag, so I am thinking I'm backed into a corner here.

**Update**
When I attempt to simply load the remote view that is surrounded with the form tag, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined kendo.all.min.js:9
kendo.initWidget kendo.all.min.js:9
w.extend._createView kendo.all.min.js:31
w.extend._createRemoteView kendo.all.min.js:31
(anonymous function) kendo.all.min.js:31
l jquery.min.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
T jquery.min.js:2
r
```

If I nest the form tag within the remote view, it works, however, that is not a viable solution.

**Update 2**
Here is a more complete example of my situation.

index.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div id="indexPageInitialView" data-role="view">
                <div data-role="content">
                    <a href="remote.aspx" data-role="button">Load remote view</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app =  new kendo.mobile.Application(document.forms[0]);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

remote.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Remote</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div id="remoteView1" data-role="view">
                <div data-role="content">
                    <h1>Hi I am a remote view</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo will load only the first view found in the remote view. So if you make the call to remote view correctly, **remoteView1** should load. If this is not the answer you are looking for, please post the full code in JSFiddle with more description.

Comment: I understand, but my problem is that the remote view page contains a form tag in which the view is nested in... so it can't correctly load. How can I get Kendo to load remote views nested within the form tag?

Comment: I have updated the original post with the error message I get when attempting to load remote views nested within the form tag.

Comment: Do you have kendo js file referred in your .aspx file? Can you post the full code in your .aspx file? I dont think <form> tag will create any issues.

Comment: Hmm... I see what you are saying... Kendo views doesn't load from a <form>. So you will have to move your view out of <form>.

Comment: Is there any such method to load from a form? I am comfortable if an area of the kendo.min.js file source could be edited to produce these results? I am stuck with having to work with webforms..

Comment: There is no such method to load from form. If you have paid license of Kendo UI , you need to contact the Kendo support for a solution.

Comment: alright, my work does have a paid license so I will ask them tomorrow I suppose. Until then, I was trying to think of an alternate route? Do you have any suggestions or maybe areas I could look in to? I am stuck using webforms, and without MVC. I also need to maintain the single page application structure, so remote views are a must.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25577/discussion-between-whizkid747-and-troy)